# Merging three rankings about economic relations

Tags: ranking

I am facing a -probably- simple or stupid problem, however I don't have the prequisite knowledge.
I would like to make an overall ranking, to compare bilateral economic relations (during a given time-frame), based on the followings:

1st ranking: Trade growth with country A - annual average (bigger the better)

```
         w Country B: -2,025% (4th) 

         w Country C: +7,4%   (2nd)

         w Country D: +7,775% (1st)

         w Country E: +2,3%   (3rd)
```

2nd ranking: Trade deficit with country A - annual average (smaller the better)

```
         w Country B: +5,05% (2nd) 

         w Country C: +7,85% (3rd)

         w Country D: +9,225%(4th)

         w Country E: -5,8%  (1st)
```

3rd ranking: total foreign direct investment from country A €million (bigger the better)

```
         w Country B: 100 (4th) 

         w Country C: 600 (3rd)

         w Country D: 1000(2nd)

         w Country E: 2100(1st)
```

Is there a statistically sound way to merge these rankings into one? A simple average of the rankings might be a bit arbitrary.. (Later I would use the overall ranking to compare with polling data of said countries about country A's economic development.)